# Showing A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (search="<html"). in my razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my controller i had given [ValidateInput(false)] for that particular Action
in my return view i also appended the search keyword also
my search keyword is **< html**

my url looks like
                 **domainname/Clients?search=< html**

In my view

```
if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("search"))
{
 string  search = Request.QueryString["search"].ToString();
}
```

then showing error

**A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (search="< html").** 
How can i correct this error in my razor view ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `requestValidationMode` to 2.0 in your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Or use view models and the `[AllowHtml]` attribute in which case you are only allowing those characters for the given property:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Search { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Search))
    {
        string search = Model.Search;
    }

    ...
}
```

In this case you don't need neither the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute, nor the `requestValidationMode="2.0"` in your web.config.

And hey, in addition to that you no longer need the magic strings in your controller action :-) You are working directly with models. Cool, isn't it?

Comment: thanks a lot it works grt for me but the value for search  get through querystring is &lt;html instead of <html

Comment: Thats the point @SreenathPlakkat. Passing HTML in a query string is a XSS vulnerability. It would be very bad to render the Search string in the response like it is. .NET is protecting your requests by throwing that exception. So, if you're making exceptions to it's protection, you need to atleast HTML decode these parameters.